# "DLL caused an exception" when calling a method that references another DLL

Tags: dll, interop, com-interop, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I developed a DLL, let's call it `DomainLogic.dll`, with some public methods through `[DllExport]` annotation. Some of those methods make calls to another DLL, let's call it `Utils.dll`. I developed a demo WinForm application with some buttons that call methods of `DomainLogic.dll` and everything works as expected.

Currently we have a partner which wants to call our `DomainLogic.dll` from their existing Visual FoxPro application.

They were able to successfully call dll methods that receive and return strings and open forms. However **when they try to call a method that internally makes a call to another DLL** (`Utils.dll`), a FoxPro error is displayed saying `"Declare DLL call caused an exception"`.

```
SET DEFAULT TO C:\Folder\Containing\DLLs
DECLARE ExampleMethod IN DomainLogic.dll
? ExampleMethod()
```

Any idea how to solve/debug this?

*More info:*

- Our DLLs require .NET 4.0, they have 4.5.2 installed.
- `Utils.dll` is correct, I successfully called the same methods using my demo app.
- We already executed the `regasm /codebase` command for both DLLs.
- We are running the FoxPro app on the same folder as the DLLs using FoxPro's `SET PATH` command.

Comment: Managed code really likes to throw exceptions when anything goes wrong.  By the time that exception makes it to Foxpro, you lost everything you could know about that exception.  All that remains is an "it didn't work" message.  It is therefore very important that write try/catch/throw code in your public methods so that the catch clause can log the exception.  Only decent way to find out what fell over.  The AppDomain.FirstChangeException event can make that less painful.  Or ask the client to use a managed debugger if you don't in fact like supporting Foxpro.  Who does.

Comment: I do. It's orders of magnitude easier to support than most of the other platforms I use. Also it's 'FirstChanceException'.

Comment: Solution here, seems like the problem is chaining strong names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631136/c-signing-dll-with-strong-name-what-about-its-dependencies

Comment: So, I have a related problem. It seems like there is no way to pass parameters by reference. I created a very simple function with just one string parameter passed by reference. When I try to call that function from VFP I'm getting DLL caused an exception error.