# C#: Signing DLL with strong name (what about its dependencies?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, assembly-signing

A while ago I asked about ["DLL caused an exception" when calling a method that references another DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020022/dll-caused-an-exception-when-calling-a-method-that-references-another-dll). On that time I had no clues but now I think what may be causing the problem.

Assume I have an `EXE` calling a `DLL1` which requires a `DLL2`. When I signed `DLL1` with a strong name, for some reason all calls to `DLL2`'s methods started returning the error below:

```
System.Exception: Error while trying to call method X from DLL1.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DLL2', Version=2.1.5899, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required.
```

**Does this mean I have to strongly name every DLL along the dependency chain?**

I had to sign the first DLL because otherwise I would get a warning during `regasm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

a signed assembly cannot call an unsigned assembly. That's part of the trust chain and it does indeed mean you will have to sign all dependencies of your signed assembly.